# Dynamically launch content script based of matching url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So this is currently hardcoded in `manifest.json`

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "css": [],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ],
```

my question is - is there a way to dynamically launch a content script for a webpage? I am actually waiting for user input in my Chrome extension, to determine which page to use a content script for.

Comment: Injecting javascript can be do with the `tabs` api. The tabs permission is required in the manifest. See chrome https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi

Comment: ah yes, I guess that's a good way to go

Answer (score 0):

you can create and written regexp as per your requirement

```
 "content_scripts": [
    {
  "matches": ["regex 1" ,"regexp 2",...."regexp N"],
      "css": [],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
 ],
```

Comment: this won't work because this is hardcoded .. in reality, the data needs to change based off user input

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just get the current page URL (location.href) and then decide whether you want to run your content script or not? 
I think this would be easiest way to do it.